# Custom headers with protractor

Tags: angular, protractor

I'm end-to-end testing my angular application.

The backend needs a custom header to work. Is there a way to set custom headers for all the requests that the browser makes?

Comment: you should include codes that you tried so far

Comment: I'm stuck on "browser.get('/');" because I don't have my custom headers set for the request.